# Google Charts - BoxPlot

Tags: google-visualization

I am trying to show a boxplot (communicating Q1, median, and Q3) for categorical test scores.  The easiest/best way I could think of is to create a column chart with the medians, set the opacity of these columns equal to 0, and then use intervals (style: 'boxes') for Q1, median, and Q3.  Here is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gyo5nLvx/

And here are the options when the column chart is drawn:

```
var options = {
  title: 'Math Test Results',
  width: 500,
  hAxis: {title: 'Subject'},
  vAxis: {minValue: 0, maxValue: 100},
  intervals: { 'lineWidth':1, 'boxWidth': .8, style: 'boxes' },
  colors:['red','green'],
  dataOpacity: 0
};
```

As you can see, the median is positioned at the height of the invisible column, Q1 is below, and Q3 is above.  This is how I ultimately want it to look - a "floating" vertical rectangle with 3 horizontal lines (one for Q1, med, and Q3).  However, there are two minor problems bugging me:

1) Because the column opacity is transparent, the user has to hover over the invisible bar in order to see the data points.  Technically, they have to hover over the lower half...if the user hovers over the top half  of the boxplot, the data points won't show (presumably because the invisible column is not under that area).  I would like for the user to hover anywhere over the box and the data will show.

2) The tooltip displays the data point and then the intervals in brackets (e.g., Midterm: 50 [40, 50, 60] ).  I find this repetitive because the median is listed twice.

I know these are minor, but as the Pareto Principle states, 80% of my time seems to be consumed by this 20% of details.  Any thoughts/suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Since the underlying column is invisible and the data points are shown elsewhere, you can just set it to 100 to span the entire height. Unfortunately, the tooltip follows suit.
2. You can override the hover text by adding a column with a role of tooltip. Yes, this means you're repeating data, but assuming your data is being built somewhere, it should be fairly easy..

Here's my version on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/48ynpzd0/

And here's the relevant code for the underlying datatable:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'x');
data.addColumn('number', 'Midterm');
data.addColumn({id:'i0', type:'number', role:'interval'});
data.addColumn({id:'i1', type:'number', role:'interval'});
data.addColumn({id:'i2', type:'number', role:'interval'});
data.addColumn({id:'tt', type:'string', role:'tooltip'});
data.addColumn('number', 'Final');
data.addColumn({id:'i0', type:'number', role:'interval'});
data.addColumn({id:'i1', type:'number', role:'interval'});
data.addColumn({id:'i2', type:'number', role:'interval'});
data.addColumn({id:'tt', type:'string', role:'tooltip'});

data.addRows([
    ['Algebra', 100, 40, 50, 60, 'Algebra Midterm: 40, 50, 60', 100, 45, 53, 74, 'Algebra Final: 45, 53, 74'],
    ['Geometry', 100, 61, 71, 84, 'Geometry Midterm: 61, 71, 84', 100, 55, 62, 69, 'Geometry Final: 55, 62, 69']]);
```

Comment: The tooltip doesn't seem to show when hovering over the actual box. Works well over the rest of the column, just not the actual box.